# Boost::asio::serial_port - using io_service.read() function when migrating to boost version 1.7.1

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a task to change version of boost library to newer and I have a problem with Boost::asio::serial_port. Right now code looks like this:

```
port_.get_io_service().run();
```

where *port_* is class private variable and it initialized like this:

```
boost::asio::serial_port port_{io_service_};
```

I am changing to version 1.7.1 and I've been reading in documentation that get_io_service() function is deleted and I should be using io_context instead of io_service. Problem is that there is no function get_io_context().
I've been reading some answers in other posts and trying to get solution, but it didn't work. I tried:

```
port_.get_executor().context().run();
port_.get_executor().run();
```

and it produces an error:

```
error: ‘class boost::asio::execution_context’ has no member named ‘run’
error: ‘boost::asio::basic_serial_port<>::executor_type’ {aka ‘class boost::asio::executor’} has no member named ‘run’
```

What did work is code like this, but it is a workaround and there must be simpler a way to do it:

```
boost::asio::io_context& io_context =
    static_cast<boost::asio::io_context&>(port_.get_executor().context());
io_context.run();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could just use the standard constructor to create an io_context. Like that:

```
boost::asio::io_context io_context;

// Submit a function to the io_context.
boost::asio::post(io_context, my_task);

// Submit a lambda object to the io_context.
boost::asio::post(io_context,
    []()
    {
      ...
    });

// Run the io_context until it runs out of work.
io_context.run();
```

from:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context.html